# How to install python's snowflake.connector.pandas_tools and use write_pandas to write a dataframe into Snowflake

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Errors I keep receiving include:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector.pandas_tools'

or

ImportError: cannot import name 'write_pandas' from 'snowflake.connector' (C:\Users\derek.lilley\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector_*init*_.py)

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the Panda extras [Using Pandas DataFrames with the Python Connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20plan%20to%20use%20the%20API%20support%20for%20Pandas%20DataFrames%2C%20you%20must%20also%20install%20the%20pandas%20extra.%20For%20details%2C%20see%20Using%20Pandas%20DataFrames%20with%20the%20Python%20Connector.) using `pip install "snowflake-connector-python[pandas]"`?